If $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution and $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $X+Y$ and $-X+Y$ have the same distribution.
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ be a probability space and $E$ be a Banach space.
Let $X:\Omega\to E$ and $Y:\Omega\to E$ be independent Banach space-valued random variables.
If $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution, i.e., $P(X\in\mathcal B)=P(-X\in \mathcal B)$ for all Borel set $B$, then show that $X+Y$ and $-X+Y$ have the same distribution.
I don't see why this holds. What I have now is :
・$P(X\in B_1, Y\in B_2)=P(X\in B_1)P(Y\in B_2)$ for all Borel set $B_1$ and $B_2$
・$P(X\in\mathcal B)=P(-X\in \mathcal B)$ for all Borel set $B$.
And I have to show that $P(X+Y\in B)=P(-X+Y\in B)$ for all Borel set $B\in\mathcal B$.
In my opinion, the flow of the proof seems to be
$$P(X+Y\in B)=P(X\in B_1)P(Y\in B_2)=P(-X\in B_1)P(Y\in B_2)=P(-X+Y\in B),$$ but I don't know whether such $B_1$ and $B_2$ exist and whether the independence of $X$ and $Y$ really guarantees $P(X+Y\in B)=P(X\in B_1)P(Y\in B_2)$ and $P(-X\in B_1)P(Y\in B_2)=P(-X+Y\in B).$
Does anyone have some idea ?

Given the hypothesis, $(X,Y)$ and $(-X,Y)$ have the same distribution, because they are equal on the rectangles. So if you compose them with $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ you get that $-X+Y$ and $X+Y$ have the same distribution.
The moral of the story is that, in this case, being independent is just a particular way of having the same joint distribution.

So, your mapping $(x,y)\to x+y$ is a mapping from $E\times E$ to $E$, isn't it ? @Matteo Gori

Yes, it's a continuous (hence measurable) map. @ips

However, letting $g(x,y)=x+y$, for Borel set $B$, I have $P(X+Y\in B)=P((X,Y)\in g^{-1}(B))$ and $P(-X+Y\in B)=P((-X,Y)\in g^{-1}(B))$, so I need $P((X,Y)\in g^{-1}(B))=P((-X,Y)\in g^{-1}(B)).$ By the equality of distribution, I have $P((X,Y)\in B_1\times B_2)=P((-X,Y)\in B_1\times B_2)$ for Borel $B_1, B_2$, but does this guarantee $P((X,Y)\in g^{-1}(B))=P((-X,Y)\in g^{-1}(B))$ ? I think $g^{-1}(B)$ is not necessarily the form $g^{-1}(B)=B_1\times B_2.$ @Matteo Gori

As I said, the independency implies that the distributions of $(X,Y)$ and $(-X,Y)$ are equal on the rectangles. But it's well-known that this implies that the distributions are equal on all the generated $\sigma$-algebra:  the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem mentioned here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system?wprov=sfla1 guarantees that two measures that are equal on a generating $\pi$-system are equal (notice that the rectangles are indeed a generating $\pi$-system).

O.K. Thank you for explaining.
